# Apache Common UrlValidator does not support unicode. alernative is avaliable?

Tags: java, validation, url

i try to url validation.
but UrlValidator is does not support unicode.
here is code

```
public static boolean isValidHttpUrl(String url) {
    String[] schemes = {"http", "https"};
    UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator(schemes);
    if (urlValidator.isValid(url)) {
        System.out.println("url is valid");
        return true;
    }
    System.out.println("url is invalid");
    return false;
}

String url = "ftp://hi.com";
boolean isValid = isValidHttpUrl(url);
assertFalse(isValid);

url = "http:// hi.com";
isValid = isValidHttpUrl(url);
assertFalse(isValid);

url = "http://hi.com";
isValid = isValidHttpUrl(url);
assertTrue(isValid);

// this is problem... it's not true... 
url = "http://안녕.com";
isValid = isValidHttpUrl(url);
assertTrue(isValid);
```

do you know any alternative url validator support unicode?

i add some case... http://seapy_hi.com  is invalid. why?
underbar is valid domain why invalid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't support IDN. You need to convert URL to Punycode first. Try this,

```
  isValid = isValidHttpUrl(IDN.toASCII(url));
```

Comment: Underscore is not allowed in domain name.

Comment: um... but some subdomain avaliable.. ex) iloveyou_too.blog.me

Comment: Yes. Underscores have been traditionally forbidden by URI RFCs, but they are now used across the web. They are now allowed according to the new [URL Standard](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/).

Comment: This code converts URL incorrectly if an URL contains scheme ("http://")

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more recent RFC that supersedes this one, but technically speaking URLs do not suppor Unicode. [RFC1738](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)

The relevant section in particular:

> No corresponding graphic US-ASCII:
>
> URLs are written only with the
>   graphic printable characters of the
>   US-ASCII coded character set. The
>   octets 80-FF hexadecimal are not
>   used in US-ASCII, and the octets 00-1F
>   and 7F hexadecimal represent
>   control characters; these must be
>   encoded.

Comment: There are already, at least, 4 standards that supersede this one ;)

Answer (score 0):

As [Kaerber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295989/apache-common-urlvalidator-does-not-support-unicode-alernative-is-avaliable/66772098#comment79191034_3296275) mention in the comment to accepted answer - that one have a bug if the string starts with a scheme.
So here's my solution with fix of that:

```java
public static String convertUnicodeURLToAscii(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    if(url == null) {
        return null;
    }
    url = url.trim();
    URI uri = new URI(url);
    boolean includeScheme = true;

    // URI needs a scheme to work properly with authority parsing
    if(uri.getScheme() == null) {
        uri = new URI("http://" + url);
        includeScheme = false;
    }

    String scheme = uri.getScheme() != null ? uri.getScheme() + "://" : null;
    String authority = uri.getRawAuthority() != null ? uri.getRawAuthority() : ""; // includes domain and port
    String path = uri.getRawPath() != null ? uri.getRawPath() : "";
    String queryString = uri.getRawQuery() != null ? "?" + uri.getRawQuery() : "";
    String fragment = uri.getRawFragment() != null ? "#" + uri.getRawFragment() : "";

    // Must convert domain to punycode separately from the path
    url = (includeScheme ? scheme : "") + IDN.toASCII(authority) + path + queryString + fragment;

    // Convert path from unicode to ascii encoding
    return new URI(url).normalize().toASCIIString();
}
```