# How to handle UNICODE URL?

Tags: java, url, unicode

If I want to pase the following URL's in Java:

[image: Screenshot of URL's in UNICODE]

... what handle should I have with the String.

So far I have been unable to handle that String's, all I've got are ???? chars.

Thanks.

Modified in 2012.09.09:

```
package pruebas;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Prueba03
{
    public static void main(String argumentos[])
    {
        Vector<String> listaURLs = new Vector<String>();

        listaURLs.add("http://президент.рф/");
        listaURLs.add("http://www.中国政府.政务.cn");
        listaURLs.add("http://www.原來我不帥.cn/");
        listaURLs.add("http://وزارة-الأتصالات.مصر/");

        URL currentURL;
        URLConnection currentConnection;
        int currentSize;

        for(int i=0; i<listaURLs.size(); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(listaURLs.get(i), URLEncoder.encode(listaURLs.get(i), "UTF-8")));
            } // End of the try.
            catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee)
            {
                uee.printStackTrace();
            } // End of the catch.
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // End of the catch.

            try
            {
                currentURL = new URL(listaURLs.get(i));
                System.out.println("currentURL" + " = " + currentURL);

                currentConnection = currentURL.openConnection();
                System.out.println("currentConnection" + " = " + currentConnection);

                currentSize = currentConnection.getContentLength();
                System.out.println("currentSize" + " = " + currentSize);
            } // End of the try.
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // End of the catch.
        } // End of the for.
    } // End of the main method.
} // End of the Prueba02 class.
```

Comment: Java strings are naturally Unicode encoded (in UTF-16). URLs need to be encoded as [Punycode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode). The problem must be somewhere else in your program flow.

Comment: Have you tried [java.net.IDN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html)?

Comment: Please see the update I added; if you can help me I appreciate it.

Comment: See this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295989/apache-common-urlvalidator-does-not-support-unicode-alernative-is-avaliable

Answer (score 1):

For domain name, you should convert unicode host name using [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode).
Punycode is a way to convert unicode string to ascii string.

The following link shows a JAVA method to convert Unicode Domain Name to International Domain Name.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html#toASCII(java.lang.String)

```
    URL u = new URL(url);
    String host = u.getHost();

    String[] labels = host.split("\\.");
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        labels[i] = java.net.IDN.toUnicode(labels[i]);
    }
    host = StringUtils.join(labels, ".");
    System.out.println(host);
```

Also, you can test some unicode URL using online punycode converter.
https://www.punycoder.com/

For example, "[http://www.中国政府.政务.cn](http://www.%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E6%94%BF%E5%BA%9C.%E6%94%BF%E5%8A%A1.cn)" is converted into "http://www.xn--fiqs8sirgfmh.xn--zfr164b.cn/".

Comment: According to that javadoc you linked, the toASCII(String) method should be used, not toUnicode().  Also, the toASCII() method already handle full hostnames, so there is no need to split up the parts first.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @hyunjong [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33213993/8868638) its not working to use `toUnicode`, use `toASCII` instead. And if you prefer kotlin, you can use this code

```
val a = "http://www.中国政府.政务.cn"

val u = URL(a);
val labels = u.host.split("\\.");
val result = labels.joinToString(separator = ".") { s ->
    java.net.IDN.toASCII(s)
}

print(result) //www.xn--fiqs8sirgfmh.xn--zfr164b.cn
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the follow code:

```
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Test7 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str = "http://www.中国政府.政务.cn";
    System.out.println(URLDecoder.decode(str, URLEncoder.encode(str,
            "UTF-8")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Eh? The second argument to decode() is an encoding name, not an encoded string.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what do you mean by "parse" - what do you intend to do with these parts? 
Arabic and Russian, as far as I know are supported by UTF-8. 
Not sure what is your source of data (some sort of Stream perhaps?) but [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has a CTOR that accepts the desired encoding. 
You should be able to obtain a string NOT containing ??? when it comes to Arabic and Russian if you use this CTOR (with the "UTF-8" argument)

Comment: Please see the update I added; if you can help me I appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

You may try use the following:

```
String pageUrl = "http://www.中国政府.政务.cn";

try 
{
        URL url = new URL(pageUrl);
        System.out.println(url.toURI().toASCIIString());
}

catch (MalformedURLException e1) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

catch (URISyntaxException e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The result is as expected:
http://www.%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E6%94%BF%E5%BA%9C.%E6%94%BF%E5%8A%A1.cn

But converting to `URI` has its own disadvantage, you should replace manually the special characters like `'|', '"', '#'` to its `URL` encoding.

Comment: This result is not correct. Unicode domains should not be percent-encoded. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name