# Java -> good url validation library, please?

Tags: java, validation, url

I am a bit shocked, that java does not contain out of the box good validation library ( **even PHP has**! ).

I tried UrlValidator from apache commons, but there is "small" problem - **it does not understand punycode.** 
 ( so, for example, for next url "http://xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai/" it gives me negative result )

Can you recommend any lib, that can properly validate urls with and without punycode ( just syntax ) ?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295989/apache-common-urlvalidator-does-not-support-unicode-alernative-is-avaliable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite simply: use `URI`.

```
try {
    URI.create("inputStringHere");
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // do whatever is needed
}
```

Checking the arguments in the URI itself (hostname, etc) is up to you, however. But the URI class can access each and every component (scheme, hostname and whatnot).